# Keep and group rows before a specific row (preserve order)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below data

```
Select          *
From            (values (1, '2022-01-15', 'a', 0, 1)
                        , (1, '2022-01-15', 'a', 1, 1)
                        , (1, '2022-01-16', 'b', 0, 1)
                        , (1, '2022-01-17', 'c', 0, 1)
                        , (1, '2022-01-18', 'c', 1, 1)
                        , (1, '2022-01-19', 'c', 1, 1)
                        , (1, '2022-01-20', 'd', 0, 1)
                ) A(visit_id, date, channel, purchase, max_purchase)
;

VISIT_ID    DATE        CHANNEL PURCHASE  MAX_PURCHASE
1           2022-01-15  a       0         1
1           2022-01-15  a       1         1
1           2022-01-16  b       0         1
1           2022-01-17  c       0         1
1           2022-01-18  c       1         1
1           2022-01-19  c       1         1
1           2022-01-20  d       0         1
```

where:

`purchase` indicates if that row had a purchase. Binary.

`max_purchase` indicates if that `visit_id` had a purchase.

Real data set has multiple `visit_id`

I am looking to (for each visit) reduce the above to:

```
Select          *
From            (values (1, 1, 'a', 1)
                        , (1, 2, 'b', 1)
                        , (1, 3, 'c', 1)
                ) A(visit_id, date, channel, max_purchase)
;

VISIT_ID  DATE  CHANNEL MAX_PURCHASE
1         1     a       1
1         2     b       1
1         3     c       1
```

Goal is to keep only the distinct channels leading up to the **final** purchase while preserving the date order. Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind getting the final output as the explanation in the above question is not detailed.

Comment: @NishantGupta In the original data. Column `channel` contains `a, a, b, b, c` but in the final we keep only `a, b` (hence the grouping, distinct nature). Furthermore, we want to create an order column `date_order` to let us know the channel order leading to the final purchase

Comment: @NishantGupta `date_order` needs to be created from column `date`

Answer (score 0):

Had to make some assumptions.... but this might be what you are looking for.

```
select visit_id, ROW_NUMBER () over (order by visit_id,channel,  max_purchase) date_order , channel,  max_purchase
from(
Select          *
From            (values (1, 1, 'a', 0, 1)
                        , (1, 1, 'a', 1, 1)
                        , (1, 2, 'b', 0, 1)
                        , (1, 3, 'b', 1, 1)
                        , (1, 4, 'c', 0, 1)
                ) A(visit_id, date, channel, purchase, max_purchase)
) a
where purchase = 1
```

Comment: Thank you @W_O_L_F
I missed out one possibility. Which is sometimes there could be channels which didn't induce a purchase but because they are before the final purchase, we still need to include them. Have updated question. Sorry for missing this out